# Two Ruby version in my environment?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I have a gem that requires at least Ruby version 2.1.5, but my version is 2.2.2p95 (As shown by `ruby -v`, returning `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]`)

I thought that the gem required only the version 2.1.5 and it wasn't compatible with newer versions of Ruby. So, my Gemfile now has the line `ruby '2.1.5'`

However, now when I run `bundle install` the console returns `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5`

I have not installed Ruby 1.9.3, I am confused as of where the console is getting this information.

I am considering downloading Ruby 2.1.5 to work on this project, but I honestly am unsure that this will solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe the `bundle` you're using is associated with the wrong Ruby. Have you tried `gem install bundler`?

Comment: I dont know whitch OS you use, but try to change PATH in you system. Maybe its set to old ruby version

Comment: @tadman That is how I installed Bundler originally.

Comment: @LukasBaliak I only have one Ruby directory in my PATH, and it is the 2.2 version.

Comment: That's good, but clearly your `bundler` is coming from another version and that's part of the problem. Are you using `rbenv` or `rvm`? 1.9.3 might be your system Ruby, and 2.2 is what you've installed using a version manager.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I haven't used either `rbenv` or `rum`.

Comment: That was `rvm` but got auto-corrected. How did you get more than one version of Ruby installed? Where did 2.2 come from? `bundler` is linked to the wrong one.

Comment: IN any case, I haven't used `rvm` either. I'm not sure where it came from, this environment is new. Ruby 2.2.2 is the first one I have installed. @tadman

Comment: I see you're on windows, try finding the bundle exectable, maybe with "where bundle" (https://superuser.com/questions/207707/what-is-windows-equivalent-of-the-which-command-in-unix-is-there-an-equivale), that might give you a clue where it is or why it is there…

Comment: @Ollie Doing the `where bundle` command pointed me to the direction of my jRuby installations `c:\jruby-1.7.20\bin\bundle` and `c:\jruby-1.7.20\bin\bundle.bat`I am now assuming that is the issue? Now I'm trying to find what that means.

Comment: I think that's it becuase JRuby is MRI 1.9.3-compliant. It is a mystery though why it finds it before MRI. Do you have it in your PATH somewhere?

Comment: @Ollie I found out I had jRuby in my PATH before Ruby. After I reinstalled Ruby, it tried to look for both  jRuby and Ruby, but found jRuby first because it was first in the path, apparently.